# Compare an autonomous differential equation with another one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y), \;\; y(0)=c.
\end{equation}
If $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all real $x$, and $z(x)$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\frac{dz}{dx}=g(z), \;\; z(0)=c.
\end{equation}
Is it true that $y(x)\geq z(x)$ for all $x\geq 0$? If so, one can possibly solve for $z$ and give a lower bound for $y$ to obtain certain properties.

When $f, g$ do not take value $0$, I try to divide and integrate to obtain
\begin{equation}
\int_{c}^{y(a)}\frac{dy}{f(y)}=\int_0^a dx=\int_{c}^{z(a)}\frac{dz}{g(z)}.
\end{equation}
Additional assumptions may give the desired result. But I am not sure if it is true in the general case, including $f,g$ possibly equal to $0$.

Comment: Consider the IVP $\dot{y} = 2\sqrt{y}$, $y(0) = 0$. One solution is $y = x^2$. Another solution is $0$ for $x \leq 1$ and  $y = (x-1)^2$ for $x \geq 1$

Comment: @Jorge Well, let's suppose $f,g$ are Lipschitz so the solutions are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comparison theorem is known (for a proof see for example W. Walter, Ordinary Differential Equations, Springer, GTM 182, p.95):

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$,  $(x,y) \mapsto F(x,y)$ be locally  Lipschitz in $y$ in the following sense: To each $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ and a number $L$ such that $|F(x,y_1)-F(x,y_2)| \le L|y_1-y_2|$ for $(x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in U$. If then $[a,b)$ is an interval ($b=\infty$ is allowed), and $u,v:[a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable functions with
$$
u(a) \le v(a) \quad \wedge \quad u'(x)-F(x,u(x)) \le v'(x)-F(x,v(x)) ~~ (x \in [a,b)),
$$
then $u(x) \le v(x)$ $(x \in [a,b))$.

In your situation, if $f$ is locally Lipschitz, we have $z(0) \le y(0)$ (even "$=$") and for $x \ge 0$ we have
$$
z'(x)-f(z(x)) \le z'(x)-g(z(x)) = 0 = y'(x)-f(y(x)),
$$
hence $z(x) \le y(x)$ $(x \ge 0)$. In particular $g$ can be arbitrary. You can also assume that $g$ is locally Lipschitz and that $f$ is arbitrary if you use the differential inequality
$$
z'(x)-g(z(x)) = 0 = y'(x)-f(y(x)) \le y'(x) - g(y(x)).
$$

Comment: Great to see it generalized to non-autonomous DEs. Thanks Gerd.